# Does there exist a linear transformation of the following type?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_5$ be any five vectors of $\mathbb R^{10}$ and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_5$ are any five elements of $\mathbb R$. Does there always exist a linear transformation $T$ from $\mathbb R^{10}$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $v_i \mapsto \alpha_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq 5$. If the answer is 'no' then my question for which cases it is possible and for which cases it is not.

Actually this question has been asked in NBHM (National Board for Higher Mathematics) interview today which I couldn't properly answer. Please help me specifying how should I proceed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $v_1 = v_2$, but $\alpha_1 \neq \alpha_2$, the function is not well-defined.

Answer (score 3):

If the vectors are linearly independent, then you can choose the values arbitrarily.

If the vectors are linearly dependent, then you can choose only values that satisfy all linear relations satisfied by the vectors. A minimal set of relations can be found using row reduction.

In practice, write the coordinates of the vectors as *rows* in a matrix $A$ and the values in a column vector $b$. Then  there exists a linear transformation taking the vectors to the values iff $A$ and the augmented matrix $[A|b]$ have the same rank.
This works because every linear transformation $\mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb R$ is given by $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \mapsto w_1 x_1 + \cdots + w_n x_n$. The rank criterion is the criterion for solvability of $Aw=b$.

Answer (score 1):

Take the $5$ scalars to be square roots of $2,3,5,7,$ and $11$. Let the 5 vectors 
(after fixing some nonzero vector $v$) be $v, 2v,\frac{197}{41}v,-7v, \frac{\pi^8}9 v$. Now think what the answer can be.

Comment: Then it is not possible. Isn't it sir?